# iPhone app: SDK 3.0 : Button Selected State: Can't get working!

Tags: iphone, configuration, button, state, selected

Trying to do simple button functionality.

Button A. It has 3 states: default, highlighted, selected.  Should UNSELECT when clicked again.
For the life of me, I can't even get a simple 3 state functionality established.

Highlight (on press) appears built in (goes to "stock" blue). 
I"ve used Button Attributes to load in image for selected state...PLayed with Control/Content to click Highlight and Selected on and off, trying to find the right combo...

I thought it'd simply be selecting in dropdown the state I want to edit....and it would register my edits for that state...images loaded/ colors changed/ etc....

NO!!!!
What am I missing..?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do set the images or titles for the different states? For that you can just use methods such as

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

OR

```
-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state;
```

is that what you are asking. May be i am misunderstanding your question because its not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a straight answer about this anywhere. So I brewed my own solution that seems to work great.

Dont forget to wire up your buttons in **IB** you will need 
to bind both 
`touch up inside` to `setButtonPressed`

`file owner` to `button` ex. `1stButton`

---

**Psuedo Code**

- Clear all buttons selected
- Set sender to selected

**CODE**

---

```
//Declare your buttons in .h

UIButton *1stButton;
UIButton *2ndButton;
UIButton *3rdButton;

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *1stButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *2ndButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *3rdButton;
```

---

```
//In .m file - write 2 methods 

-(void)clearButtons
{
    [1stButton setSelected:FALSE];
    [2ndButton setSelected:FALSE];
    [3rdButton setSelected:FALSE];
}

//attach to touch up inside event in IB for each button

-(void) setButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    self.clearButtons;
    [sender setSelected:TRUE];
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should post some code (or an IB screenshot) as it's hard to fully parse what you are saying.

The default behavior of a UIButton is to show the Selected state on press, then revert back to the normal state. If you want it to "lock down" a press, you need to do something like this in the IBAction hooked to the UIButton:

```
BOOL pressed;
UIButton *button

- (IBAction) toggleButton:(id)sender
{
    button.selected = ! pressed;
    pressed = ! pressed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AH! Well, not being a programmer,  I was hoping for simple "stock" solution within Interface Builder.

To be clear of the "want/wish:

Button A-E. Each button should have 3 states: Default, highlight, selected.
Default: resting state.
Highlight: some treatment using interface builder features or import a graphic that will appear on Highlight. This state appears while button is being pressed.
Selected: when button A-E is released, it shows that it has been selected by displaying a new state, again by using tweaks within interface builder (font color, shadow) or import a graphic.  When you click the SELECTED button again, it returns to Default state.

I guess I just thought it'd be "easy" because SDK 3.0 Interface Builder has dropdowns for the 3 states. I thought code would "magically" be assigned to the button allowing it to function as desired along with it's aesthetic shift.

I TOTALLY appreciate any and all feedback. I can pass along any coding advice to partner on this App.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *img2 = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
UIImage *img3 = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"image3.png"];

[button setImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:img2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setImage:img3 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setImage:img2 forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted+UIControlStateSelected)];

[img1 release];
[img2 release];
[img3 release];
```

This is because the state variable is actually a bit flag.